# How does let in for loop work?

Tags: javascript, scope, var, let

```
var messages = ["Check!", "This!", "Out!"];

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(messages[i]);
  }, i * 1500);
}
// -> prints 3* undefined


for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(messages[i]);
  }, i * 1500);
}
// -> prints out the array
```

I understand how "var" works and I'm quite used to it - the scope is functional. However the let statement is far from clear. I understand is has block scope, but why does THAT matter in the example?  In that example the for loop is long time over with in both cases. Why does let print out the array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4028085

Comment: What exactly are you printing ?

Comment: That the loop is long time over doesn't matter - JS has closures. And those close over block scopes just as well

Answer (score 2):

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the var keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.

Check out here more detailed info 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let